# Adding an onclick event to Wix form

Tags: javascript, velo

**Reason for question:** To create a Custom Onclick to trigger Bing conversion stats

Hi All, 
Hoping someone can help. I've developed a website using Wix, I am intending to launch an updated site and drive traffic to it using Bing ads, to test A/B Homepage to maximise lead generation/interest.

**Journey** 
Bing ad > Home page > enter email address and subscribe.

**Problem**
I'm familiar with HTML and some Javascript but I'm not familiar with using Wixcode and all I want to do is modify the Submit button on subscribe form (Wix prebuilt) to add an onclick event, to trigger the BingAd and submit the form so I know that record it as a conversion.

The site is zeux.com (this isn't the updated, but you can see the form at the button).

The Bing code I need to fire is:

```js
<script>
window.uetq = window.uetq || []; 
window.uetq.push
({ 'ec':'Event category', 'ea':'Event action', 'el':'Event label', 'ev':'Event value' }); 
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you set custom js to your wix?

Comment: I can have access to the Head section of the site and I've used it to add custom code from tags such as Google Analytics, so I assume I can do the same here.

Comment: As far as I've seen using Wix Code for a couple months, you can't access DOM variables or Window variables from the site itself.

Answer (score 0):

Wix recently introduced an extension to the Wix Window API called [trackEvent](https://www.wix.com/code/home/forum/product-updates/send-events-to-3rd-party-analytics-apps)
which sends custom event data to 3rd party analytics apps. For example :

```
//...
import wixWindow from 'wix-window';
wixWindow.trackEvent("AddProductImpression", {
      contents: [{
        sku: "P12345",
        name: "Really Fast Running Shoes",
        category: "Apparel/Shoes",
        price: 100,
        currency: "USD",
        brand: "Nike",
        variant: "Black",
        list: "Search Results",
        position: 1
      }]
 });
```

You can find out more at the [wixWindow.trackEvent API Reference.](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-window.html#trackEvent)

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'll have a look